# Is there an api available to configure/trigger or create new scheduled incremental refreshes for AWS Quicksight datasets?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-quicksight

I have a requirement where I need to refresh my dataset programmatically every x minutes. Now this value of x could change based on some other parameters like how frequently new data is coming or based on user activity on dashboards, decided by another logic which is not part of the problem here.
As far as I have read from aws documentation **createingestion** api is the only way I can programmatically trigger a full refresh.

But wanted to know if I can create incremental refreshes using apis/sdk ? How can I configure the incremental refresh parameters like look-back window and column name using apis, like we configure in console?

How can I create schedule refreshes using apis/sdk ?

Any suggestions or work arounds to implement this if apis not available, much appreciated.

Comment: Have you found anything actionable?

Comment: I am still looking for a solution. Do you have any progress with that?